# CMD script - make copy of png file in current folder but with new name?

Tags: windows, command-line

I have different folders in which is one *.png file and this script.cmd file.
Script after doubleclick need to make copy of png file inside this folder but with suffix **- 1000px**. After this script run next line, one exe against this *1000px.png file. Remark, different folders, so script need to use current folder path where she is and make copy of png file in this same folder.

First line is problem, second line work. Cant make copy of .png file. This first line work (for %f in (*.png) do copy "%~f" "%~nf - 1000px%~xf") if I navigate to folder in cmd window and run code but wont work from double click on script.cmd file. I try with %% and full path to png file but no success.

```
  for %%f in (*.png) do copy "%%~f" "%%~nf - 1000px%%~xf"
  for %%a in ("C:\Radni\Desktop\Folder\*1000px.png") do (start "" /w "c:\radni\desktop\u png 1000px visine.exe" "%%a")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I found way. This is for automating Photoshop to do something on png pictures via droplet.exe

Copy script to same folder as picture(s)...Run script which make copy of png file with suffix " - 1000px" and than call Photoshop droplet to do something with this *1000*.png file(s).

```
for %%f in (*.png) do copy "%%~f" "%%~nf - 1000px%%~xf"
for %%A in (*1000*.png) do c:\radni\desktop\png1000.exe "%%~fA"
```